# Оптимизация MPI программы

Tags: c, многопоточность, mpi

Для университета делаю программу решения СЛАУ на MPI методом вращения. Получается в итоге, что чем больше узлов, тем медленее работает программа. Уже минимизировал сетевую пересылку до минимума, все равно тормозит.

Исходный код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 3

static void fill_equation(double matr[N + 1][N]) {
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < N + 1; ++j) {
            fscanf(stdin, "%lf", &matr[j][i]);
        }
    }
}

static double sqr(double a) {
    return a * a;
}

static void transform_matrix(int proc_id, double matr[][N], int columns_per_proc) {
    int i, j, k;
    for (i = 0; i < N - 1; ++i) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < N; ++j) {

            double c = 0.0, s = 0.0;

            int worker_with_i = i / columns_per_proc;
            double buf[2];

            buf[0] = matr[i % columns_per_proc][i] / sqrt(sqr(matr[i % columns_per_proc][i]) + matr[i % columns_per_proc][j]);
            buf[1]= matr[i % columns_per_proc][j] / sqrt(sqr(matr[i % columns_per_proc][i]) + matr[i % columns_per_proc][j]);

            MPI_Bcast(&buf, 2, MPI_DOUBLE, worker_with_i, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

            c = buf[0];
            s = buf[1];

            static double first_equation_copy[N + 1];
            static double second_equation_copy[N + 1];

            for (k = 0; k < columns_per_proc; ++k) {
                first_equation_copy[k] = matr[k][i];
                second_equation_copy[k] = matr[k][j];

                matr[k][i] = first_equation_copy[k] * c + second_equation_copy[k] * s;
                matr[k][j] = second_equation_copy[k] * c - first_equation_copy[k] * s;
            }
        }
    }
}

static void solve(int proc_id, int proc_num, double matr[N + 1][N]) {
    int i, j;
    int columns_per_proc = ceil((N + 1.0) / proc_num);

    void *work_buffer = malloc(columns_per_proc * N * sizeof(double));

    MPI_Scatter(matr, columns_per_proc * N, MPI_DOUBLE, work_buffer,
            columns_per_proc * N, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    transform_matrix(proc_id, work_buffer, columns_per_proc);

    MPI_Gather(work_buffer, columns_per_proc * N, MPI_DOUBLE, matr, columns_per_proc * N,
            MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (proc_id == 0) {

        for(i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            for (j = 0; j < N + 1; ++j) {
                printf("%lf ", matr[j][i]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }

    }

    free(work_buffer);
}

static void solve_equation(int proc_id, int proc_num) {
    static double matr[N + 1][N];
    if (proc_id == 0) {
        fill_equation(matr);
    }

    solve(proc_id, proc_num, matr);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int  proc_id; /* rank of process */
    int  proc_num;       /* number of processes */

    /* start up MPI */

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    double start = MPI_Wtime();


    /* find out process rank */
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &proc_id);

    /* find out number of processes */
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &proc_num);

    solve_equation(proc_id, proc_num);

    double stop = MPI_Wtime();

    if (proc_id == 0) printf("Used %lf seconds", stop - start);

    /* shut down MPI */
    MPI_Finalize(); 

    return 0;
}
```

Возможно как-то можно будет сократить MPI_Bcast из 44 строки, но пока не придумал как. Профилировка показывает, что около 90% тратится именно на MPI_Bcast.